# Showing that $S^1 \times \left\{\pm 1 \right\}$ is not isomorphic to $O(2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to show that $S^1 \times \left\{\pm 1 \right\}$ , where $S^1$ is the set of complex numbers with absolute value $1$, is not isomorphic to $O(2)$, the set of $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrices under matrix multiplication.

Earlier on in the same question I showed that $S^1$ is isomorphic to $SO(2)$, the set of $2 \times 2$ matrices with determinant $1$ under matrix multiplication, I say this as I think it's relevant to showing this isn't isomorphic.

I can't see how it's possible to find a map from $S^1 \times \left\{\pm 1 \right\}$ to $O(2)$ since $S^1 \times \left\{\pm 1 \right\}$ will be of the form $(z, \pm 1)$, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$ so while it's possible to put $z$ alone into a $2 \times 2$ matrix, I don't see how it can be done for  $(z, \pm 1)$, but I don't know how to put this mathematically.

Thanks, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

> A commutative group cannot be isomorphic to a non-commutative group.

Comment originally posted by Derek Holt, writing here to move the question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

A more specific reason is that $O(2)$ contains infinitely many elements of order 2 (all the reflections for example) but $S^1\times \{\pm1\}$ contains only 3.